# JQuery UI buttonset - onmouseleave remove ui-active-state

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to use a very simple buttonlist. When the page loads everything is fine, the selected value is selected and it looks right.

the problem starts when i move the mouse over the button, as soon as i leave the button, the ui-active-state class gets removed - the aria-pressed attribute is still set to true, but the styling is gone.

So of course, I fired up firebug and took a look.

In jquery.ui

`.bind( "mouseleave.button", function() {
    if ( options.disabled ) {
     return;
    }
    $( this ).removeClass( hoverClass );
   })`

is getting called 2x, the second time hover class is equal to 'ui-hover ui-active-state' which is obviously the problem, i just have no idea why.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key actually ended up being a rogue watermark plugin. It cause jquery ui to process both the label and radio button individually.

Comment: so how did you fix this problem?

Comment: We changed out the watermark plugin we were using, thus jquery ui worked as designed